# ROS/OpenCV/Flask - How to stream?

Tags: opencv, flask, ros

I'm trying to create a web stream interface of a camera that is connected to ROS.
A node publishes photo of the camera every 2 seconds to this topic: webcam/image_raw

```
image_message = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame_empty, encoding="bgr8")
pub_image_raw.publish(image_message)
```

And the other node subscribes to it and renders it on a web page via Flask.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import threading
import cv2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, Response


app = Flask(__name__)

bridge = CvBridge()

cv_image = 0

def callback(data):
    global cv_image
    try:
        cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
        #cv2.imshow("Image window", cv_image)
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)


threading.Thread(target=lambda: rospy.init_node('test_node5', disable_signals=True)).start()
image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("webcam/image_raw", Image, callback)


def gen():
    global cv_image
    while True:
        #success, image = video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv_image)
        frame = jpeg.tobytes()
        
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # from og server
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Until now it's kinda working but there is a lot of random errors.
Is there a way to improve this code?
Thank!

Comment: What sort of errors are you seeing specifically? At the very least that loop inside `gen()` should probably be rate limited via `rospy.Rate()`

Comment: In a similar use case I decided to opt for http://wiki.ros.org/web_video_server rather than implementing message to image generation and having to update the page on each new message. The stream is easily embed-able using `<img src="http://server:8080/stream?topic=/usb_cam/image_raw" />`